# D3 Equivalent to jQuery Attribute selector

Tags: jquery, select, d3.js

Does anyone know the d3 equivalent to jQuery attribute selector:

```
$('[attribute="name"]')
```

I want to be able to use d3 methods such as .transition().  Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's the same in both D3 and jQuery; the underlying functionality is provided by the [W3C Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors), so see the documentation on attribute selectors. For example, `d3.select("[id=body]")` is equivalent to `d3.select("#body")`.

Comment: mike .. are you sure there's not some difference in implementation? `$("svg.overview").find(".node[data-index=0]")` returns the element, `d3.select("svg.overview").selectAll(".node")` returns the element and 6 others - while `d3.select("svg.overview").selectAll(".node[data-index=0]")` throws "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '.node[data-index=0]' is not a valid selector.
    at SVGSVGElement.<anonymous>"

Comment: ah ! it's ok if i quote the value ie `.node[data-index='0']`