# selecting by attribute ala select(["name=Myriel"])

Tags: d3.js

i am missing something basic about d3 selection.  using the [basic d3 force layout example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045), i want to select a particular node, say `Myriel` and make it fixed.  following previous hints like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11044408/1079688) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/iRrVcIDpodM), it seems `myrielNode = d3.select(["name=Myriel"])` should do it but does not?  i've also tried `filter()` based strategies, ...  what am i doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myrielDomNode = d3.select('[name="Myriel"]');
var myrielDatum = myrielDomNode.datum();
myrielDatum.fixed = true;
```

This of course assumes a DOM node exists that has an attribute `name="Myriel"` and is bound to data such that `datum()` is an object controlled by the force layout.

#### Update

Turns out that `name` was not an attribute of the DOM node, but rather an attribute of the data. In this case, finding the `Myriel` node becomes a find operation (via filter) on the data array:

```
myrielNode = nodes.filter(function(d) { return d.name == 'Myriel'; })[0]
```

Comment: as your solution began the same as @Stephen's i started with that (adding additional quotes).  as i replied to him, that isn't helping.  but i do match your assumptions: i can grab a mouse-click event, get a `<g>` DOM element, and it does have a fixed property the force layout respects?

Comment: @rikb It's not just the quotes that you're missing, but more importantly, the parentheses are missing (at least from the example you provided).

Comment: ah! bad typo in my original post, sorry @Stephen.  I edited that to include the parens; I HAD been using them.  and to be complete, let me also say that (when i use a checkpoint with a mouse-click interupt i find) the `g` DOM element also has the correct `name` attribute.   such a simple `select()` not working, it's driving me nuts!

Comment: @rikb Could there be more than a single DOM element with `name=Myriel`? `d3.select()` only returns the first one it finds, so if there are multiples, you need to work around it. `d3.selectAll()` will return a list of matches, but `datum()` will only return the first match's datum. If you also have jQuery on the page, you can use the developer console to check what you get with `$('[name="Myriel"]')`, or if you don't have jQuery, you can check whether (again, from the console) `d3.selectAll('[name="Myriel"]').size()` yields anything other than 1.

Comment: @Stephen, no the names in [mbostock's miserables example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) are unique.  and if `selectAll()` returned ANYTHING other than arrays of null i'd be happy; both `select()` and 'selectAll()` return arrays of nulls(:

Comment: and sorry again @meetamit, i just realized i've been referring to you as Stephen (:

Comment: @rikb No probs. But I'm now realizing that there might be a disconnect here: all of the above assumes that the nodes have `name` attributes in the DOM. I.e. the circles would look something like `<circle class="node" name="Myriel" r="5" cx="..." ...></circle>`. The Les Mis example does not have any `name` attributes. So unless your code is adds them, your viz doesn't have them either, & none of the above is applicable. It's now sounding to me like you mean that the JavaScript objects (the `d`) that correspond to those nodes hold the `name` attribute. Correct? If so, you can't use `d3.select`.

Comment: In this case you just need to find the Myriel node within the array that you pass to the force layout: `graph.nodes.filter(function(d) { return d.name == 'Myriel'; })[0].fixed = true`.

Comment: that was the hint i was missing @meetamit, just the trailing `[0]` suffix!  you win the Answered check, and my thanks.

Comment: for posterity, what i was looking for was `myrielNode = nodes.filter(function(d) { return d.name == 'Myriel'; })[0];`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
d3.select('[name="Myriell"]');
```